# I'm trying to do a post with an ajax call from javascript to an spring mvc backend, but my controller doesn't seem to receive the modelattributes

Tags: spring, rest, jquery, spring-mvc

Here's my code

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/trip/mail.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String mailForm(@ModelAttribute(value="formulier") String   formulier, @ModelAttribute(value="orgMessage") String orgMessage, @ModelAttribute(value="tripID") String tripID, BindingResult result) {
    ModelMap mailModel = new ModelMap();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    mailModel.addAttribute("title", "Trip update");
    mailModel.addAttribute("subtitle1", "Message from organiser");
    mailModel.addAttribute("message", orgMessage);
    mailModel.addAttribute("subtitle2", "The following trip changes occured");
    mailModel.addAttribute("text", formulier);
    mailModel.addAttribute("date", format.format(new Date()));

    SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage(message);
    msg.setTo("kdgteamf@gmail.com");
    tripService.sendMail(mailModel, msg);
    return "Congrats!";
```

javascript:

```
var formInhoud = $("#changes").html();
var organiserMessage = $("#Message").val();
var tripID = $("#hiddenTripID").val();
$("#dialog-message").css("cursor", "wait");
```

`$.post("/ProjectTeamF-1.0/trip/mail.html",
        { formulier: formInhoud, orgMessage: organiserMessage, tripID: tripID},
        function (data) {
            $("#viewTripForm").submit();
        }
    );`

I'm trying to send an email from my backend spring mvc and this all works, but I'm having problems with my post. When I execute my javascript it works fine and "mailForm" works normaly in my controller (my email is send). The only problem is that I don't seem to receive those 3 modelattributes which contain information I'd like to add to my mail. There just empty when I print them in my console and I'm sure the right information is in them in the javascript. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm new to spring mvc, rest services and all that, also new to stackoverflow so I hope my question is clear enough and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: have you checked the console for reference errors?

Answer (score 1):

Something like @RequestParam("formulier") instead of modelattribute in controller method would solve your problem. But rather create an object /container/bean which would represent your data and this bean should have fields which are posted. And then you can create this bean as ModelAttribute.
For example container bean FormBean with fields formulier etc with proper getter and setters. And then in controller method use actionMethod(@ModelAttribute("beanInJsp") FormBean formBean )